# Как вызвать функцию по завершении таймера?

Tags: таймер, c++, функции

Я удивлён, что не нашёл ничего вменяемого по этому вопросу. Но всё же, как в с++ вызвать некую функцию по завершении таймера? Вопрос достаточно банальный однако. Подозреваю, что тут не обойдётся без `boost::bind.`

Нужен аналог данного:

```
QTimer::singleShot(100, this, SLOT(onTimeExpired()));
```

Comment: Просто установить setitimer() и обрабатывать сигнал SIGALRM Вам не подходит?

Часто это самое простое решение (для однопоточной программы). Перехватываете сигнал и выставляете флаг.

Comment: Долго искал, но на подобное решение не наталкивался. В одну строчку решение: 
signal(SIGALRM, &handler); 

А для многопоточной проги не подойдёт? У меня несколько объектов одного класса, в котором используется таймер, предполагается, что они будут в разных потоках.

Comment: Да, Вы так задаете обработчик сигнала, который будет сгенерен в результате setitimer() (или его обертки alarm(в секундах)). Обработчик будет вызван в произвольном (любом) потоке. 

Подойдет или нет? От логики Вашей программы (поведения объектов в разных потоках) зависит.

Comment: Насколько я понял, это непереносимое решение. А значит не подходит(

Comment: Условная компиляция - это терпимо. Да она и не понадобится, если использовать   boost::timer::cpu_timer  Там наносекунды, но погрешность не велика - порядка сотых, тысячных секунды, что вполне терпимо.

Comment: А boost более переносим, чем posix?

Comment: @avp, там, где дело касается системного программирования, boost - это  фактически переносимая оболочка для posix и WinAPI.

Comment: @mikillskegg, спасибо. 

Кстати, проблем со статической линковкой с библиотеками boost нет? Лицензии и т.п.

Comment: Boost абсолютно свободное ПО. Линкуйте как хотите. Кстати, по умолчанию он собирается как раз с обоими типами библиотек.

Comment: @avp: если верить вот [этому](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG31-C.+Do+not+access+shared+objects+in+signal+handlers) (найдено [здесь](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/28/8781423.aspx)), в обработчике сигнала практически ничего полезного сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Озадачали Вы меня. Вот тут на досуге набросал что-то.

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace MyTimer {

class  Timer {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thr;

    template <typename Callable> class _func {
        unsigned int dur;   
        Callable& cb;

        public:     
        _func (long long _dur, const Callable& _cb): dur (_dur), cb((Callable&)  _cb) {}
        void operator() () {    
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(dur));            
            cb();           
        }           
    };

public:
    template <typename Callable> Timer (long long _dur, const  Callable& _cb)  {
        _func<Callable> ff (_dur, _cb);
        thr.reset (new boost::thread(ff));  
    }

    ~Timer() {}

     Timer (const Timer& tm) {
        this->thr = tm.thr;
    }

    Timer operator= (const Timer& tm) {
        if (this != &tm) this->thr = tm.thr;
        return *this;
    }

    void interrupt () {
        thr->interrupt();
    }
};

}
```

Это все оформляется в виде хедера. Используется очень просто.

```
 MyTimer::Timer Tm1 (5000, func);
```

Первый параметр - время ожидания в миллисекундах, второй - вызываемый объект. Может быть простая функция, может быть функтор. Главное, не имеет параметров и возвращает void.

Можно прервать ожидание с помощью метода interrupt()

Испытывал в лине, gcc4.6 и 4.7  и icpc 12, boost 1.49 и 1.51

Comment: В 2012 это было правильно. Однако теперь это всё можно сделать парой строк на стандартных заголовках - std::thread и std::chrono. Это я, так сказать, для потомков.

Answer (score 3):

Простейший вариант :

```
#include <signal.h>

void sighandler(int signum) {
    // Что-то делаем по прерыванию от таймера
};

int main () {

   // Устанавливаем обработчик прерывания
   signal(SIGALRM, sighandler);

   // Задаём интервал 5 секунд
   alarm(5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я честно не знаю "аналога", но если уж совсем ничего, то к вопросу:

> как в с++ вызвать некую функцию по завершении таймера?

могу предложить вот такой вот недокод ;) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>    /* _beginthread, _endthread */
#include "Windows.h"

typedef void(*run_func)();

class singleShot {
    public:
    singleShot(_time_out, run_func _func, bool run_now = true)
        : time_out(_time_out), func(_func)
    {
        if (run_now) run();
    }
    static void thread_func( void *ch )
    {
        singleShot* obj = static_cast<singleShot*>(ch);
        Sleep(obj->time_out);
        obj->func();
        _endthread();
    }
    void run() {_beginthread(thread_func, 0, (void*)this);}
    void set_params(_time_out, run_func _func) {time_out=_time_out; func=_func;}

    int time_out;
    run_func func;
};

void MyTimeOutFunc();
singleShot SecondUse(0, 0, false);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    singleShot FirstUse(1000, MyTimeOutFunc);
    //можно и так использовать, главное не дать
    //удалиться объекту до выполнения функции :   
    Sleep(2000);

    //Лучьше так:
    SecondUse.set_params(2000, MyTimeOutFunc);
    SecondUse.run();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void MyTimeOutFunc()
{
    printf("\nHello world!!!\n");
}
```

Comment: Только здесь надо четко осознавать, что функция в другом потоке вызовется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы функцию через заданное время хотите вызвать?

Если в ***nix**, то посмотрите на man-ы `timer_create`, `timer_delete`, `timer_settime`, `timer_gettime`. Это "POSIX
       (interval)  timers"

В убунте (думаю в других тоже) в man `timer_create` есть пример.

Можно одновременно делать несколько таймеров, которые могут быть "одноразовыми" (one short) или переодически срабатывающими. Время можно задавать как реальное, так и виртуальное (время процесса или потока).

Интервал времени задается в секундах и наносекудах(!) (IMHO этим *нано* верить нельзя, но миллисекунды в моих тестах отрабатывались).

Если интересно, могу выложить кусок кода, правда в нем вместо вызова функции посылается сигнал определенному потоку (что делать по истечении таймера - сигнал или вызов функции, задается в timer_create).

Comment: Хотелось бы переносимого решения

Comment: Переносимого для *всех* систем с С++? Винда, никсы, мак, встроенные системы и т.д.?

Вы задачку свою (ее общие черты) поподробней распишите, тогда может что и найдется. Может Вам для нее и не нужны асинхронные таймеры.

Comment: Загружать странички по истечении некоторого количества секунд 30 - 500. Это будет делаться несколькими объектами в разных потоках (а может и в пуле потоков, что лучше).
не для всех, а для винды, никсов.

Comment: @VladD, там где Вы недавно комментировали у меня лимит исчерпался....

Вы правильно заострили внимание на проблемах с signal handler. Вот здесь есть список [Async-signal-safe functions](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) того, что можно вызывать.

Также актуальна проблема "race condition" почти с любыми данными даже для однопоточной программы.

Но, обратите внимание, что можно делать write (в pipe, socket) и можно использовать select (или аналоги) в основном цикле для получения данных из обработчика.

--

Хотя, IMHO лучше просто выставлять флаг и не злоупотреблять сигналами.